# When i insert a table row why it won't be highlighted?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

My html+js+form.html:

http://pastebin.com/Pe4apW02

I have also a css, but its not important now. So my problem is, when i insert a new row, it wont be highlighted, just the others which is  i created the table in the beginning. 
I tried:

```
    $("#shipmentTable tr").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    });
```

and css for the table:

```
        .member tr.selected {
        background-color: rgba(41, 103, 182, 0.89);
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

but what i said i isnt working correctly. Can anyone helps to me?

Comment: this happens because you set the handler over the already existant rows. search for event delegation on SO

Comment: no, if i create a new row it isnt highlighted

Comment: So you now are saying it does not work on dynamically created rows? That would because a new row would not have the event attached... Events do not get bound automatically.

Comment: `$("#shipmentTable").on("click", "tbody tr", function(){ });`